# `update-alternatives --list editor` does not show editors installed via `snap`

Tags: snap, update-alternatives

```
$ update-alternatives --list editor
/bin/nano
/usr/bin/code
/usr/bin/vim.tiny
```

`update-alternatives --list editor` does not show `nvim` which I installed using snap. Even though my `PATH` variable contains `/snap/bin`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not all packages register themselves as an alternative. You can manually add `nvim` as an alternative for `editor` using [`update-alternatives`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives).

```bsh
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /snap/bin/nvim 1111
```

Comment: This is why I'll be staying on 18.04 for a while longer.   Maybe migrate to some other Debian derivative.

Comment: @RonJohn I don't think this has to do something with Ubuntu. May be it's a snapcraft thing. Anyway, the first thing I always do on a new installation is `sudo apt purge snapd`.

Comment: Isn't Ubuntu moving to mostly a snap-based environment?

Comment: @RonJohn As long as it's Debian based, I won't mind. I can still find deb packages. I'm currently using 20.04 and I don't miss snaps :)